# Percentage in JavaFX 8 CSS

Tags: css, javafx

JavaFX 8 CSS documentation says that it is possible to use percentage in a value of type [number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepercentage).

I want to set the font size of a specific Label 20% of its size (or its parent size). However, if I set `-fx-font-size: 20%;`, the font becomes very small. And no matter whether I expand its size or its parent size, the font size remains the same. I have tried with different panes (AnchorPane, FlowPane, HBox, etc) as well but no success.

Is this the expected behaviour of the percentage? Is there a way to set dynamic sizes with JavaFX CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind a value to Font Size and apply it using styleProperty(), like this:

```
DoubleProperty fontSize22 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(22);
fontSize22.bind(stage.widthProperty().add(stage.heightProperty()).divide(90));
homeButton.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", fontSize22.asString(), "px;"));
```

Comment: Is it possible using external CSS file?

Comment: @Line, yes but this is another question.

Comment: I think what @Line is asking is if it can be done exclusively with CSS, no code involved - which is what I meant by asking the question.